# Using template functions in Visual Studio C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

0Dear StackExchange Community,

I have for two hours tried to find the source of the problem but failed completly. Research=google search also did not provide any viable solutions. At least I was able to discover that under VS 6.0 one cannot split the declaration and implementation of a template function between header and .cpp-file.

Perhaps my approach is inherently flawed or it is VS 6.0 that is being particulary obnoxious this time.

Here is the test code I wrote.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class TestClass{

  public:
     template<class T> inline bool isNull(T& inObject){
        return 0;   // edited because of the answer by Joachim Pileborg  :)
                // initial code was: return (inObject != NULL) ? 0:1; 
  }

};

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout<<TestClass::isNull<string>("test");
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code causes the following error:

*fatal error C1001: INTERNER COMPILER- FEHLER
        (Compiler-File "msc1.cpp", Row 1794)*

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

P.S. : this time i really endevoured to ask the question as precisly as possible also providing a concrete example. Please let me know if there is anything else I should have added.

P.SS: I know that visual studio 6.0 ist pretty old but I am forced to use it at work. Running the same code with the a new compiler (at home) did not cause any errors. This is why I assume that the problem is mainly caused by the whims of VS 6.0.

Thanks in advance for you help !!
JD

Comment: Why use the ternary operator? Just use return the result of the comparison as it's already a boolean.

Comment: VC++ 6.0 support for templates was quite lacking. You could try 1) helping the compiler by constructing the argument explicitly instead of relying on conversions `cout << TestClass::isNull<string>(string("test"));`, or ...

Comment: 2) not specifying the template argument explicitly `cout << TestClass::isNull(string("test"))`, or ...

Comment: 3) fixing the error in the template (you can't compare a `string` with `NULL`)

Comment: And, the template should take its argument as `const T&`, since you're passing temporaries into it.

Comment: And as @StephaneRolland pointed out, the function must be declared `static` to be called through the class.

Comment: “I know that visual studio 6.0 ist pretty old but I am forced to use it at work” – quit the job. This is the most constructive advice I can give you, I’m afraid. If your company doesn’t care enough to provide you with adequate tools they’re a bad employer.

Comment: you are probably better off fetching a new fresh vs2012 express version - if you are not tied to vs6 for some reason.

Comment: i would - but i am not allowed to install it - even though it is free. It security consideres anything it hasn't checked for 4 month a potential threat ...

Comment: @ Angew so basically the best option i have besides quitting my job is to forgo the use of template functions :(  ?

Comment: @AndreyLujankin Not necessarily, but you'll have to be prepared for hitting problems such as this every now and then. Does it help if you apply all the corrections (`static`, `const&`, don't compare `string` and `NULL`)?

Comment: @Andrey Lujankin: you have removed some of the compilation errors in the your code of your question why ?

Comment: @Angew - I tried replacing inline with statis (doesnt help). I also made `isNull` return 0 all the time (see code above) and even this did not help. could it be that the distribution of VC++ 6.0 i have installed does not support templates at all ?

Comment: @ Stephane Rolland - I removed it to see whether the code would compile if I the function only returned 0 for alle imputs (unfortunately it does). This way the question pertains more the functionaly of VC++ 6.0 and less to my inability to code correctly.

Comment: And could somebody tell me why my question was downvoted again ...

Comment: @AndreyLujankin It has (parts of) the standard library, so it must support at least *some* templates. However, it might be that it can't handle a member function template of a non-template class. Try a minimal example with a primitive type instead of `string`, just to be sure.

Comment: I tried `cout<< TestClass::isNull<int>(2);` and it still throws the same error.  Perhaps I have to change some settings or something like that ...

Comment: "INTERNER COMPILER- FEHLER" is German for "Internal compiler error". So it's a VC++ 6 bug. Also, VC++ 6 is now 15 years old. You really need to talk to your IT security people about allowing a new compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you define a custom casting operator that returns a pointer, an object instance can never be equal to `NULL`.

Comment: okey id did not know that thanks- still i updated my code to just return 0 all the time and it still throws the same error :(

Comment: @AndreyLujankin Then I think it's time you think about updating Visual Studio. Version 6 is _ancient_, and contains quite a few bugs that won't be fixed.

Comment: okey i will try pleading with the IT-department ... I do not think they will listen. I am the only person coding in C++ so they won't be very motivated to cater to my needs

Answer (score 1):

Apart from facts noted in comments and answers, internal compiler error happens in situation, when there's a bug in the compiler, that prevents it from compiling valid code.

Microsoft usually fixes these bugs in IDE hotfixes or in newer versions of compilers. Try to modify the structure of code such that it does the same thing, but looks differently - it's the only way to avoid the Internal Error problem.

Comment: any Idea how i could do that in the particular case described above ?

Comment: Have you read all answers? You may as well always return false, because it is not possible to pass a reference to a NULL object. It would make sense if you passed a pointer - in which case there would be no need for templates, effectively solving the problem.

Comment: I did try to always return 0 - i even altered the code above accordingly. The thing is it seems that I cannot use any templates at all. I tried constructing the simplest examples possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are **several troubles** in your code:

I rewrote it this way:

- comparing the adress of the reference you're passing (you have edited your question but you wrote `inObject==NULL` in the body of your function and it couldn't compile either)
- using const string& so has to be able to call `TestClass::isNull<string>("test");`
- you must define your function as static if you want to call it the way you do
- I'm not sure but the character '<' following your word template looked badly encoded in my IDE, so I replaced it with a commonplace `<`, it compiled better
- it's a way of coding, but prefer using typename than class when defining templates
- prefer using `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0` ( you edited your question but you still return 0...)

=>

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class TestClass{

  public:
    template<typename T> 
    static bool isNull(const T& inObject)
     {
        return (&inObject == NULL) ? true : false;
    }

};

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout<< TestClass::isNull<string>("test");
    return 0;
}
```

Now it compiles fine.

Comment: thank you :)   -  I tried running your code but I still get the same error. Must be really a problem with VS 6.0

Comment: did you try it with VS C++ 6.0 ?

Comment: @Angrew you're right, I'm sure it doesn't work :-) I modify the code

Comment: @Andrey no I am glad I will never put my hands again on VC 6.0. I use VC 10.0 at work right now. And hope to leave it soon for VC 11.0 so ase to be more C++11 compliant.

Comment: @Andrey and there's no way you can have a more recent VC ?

Comment: References can never be NULL!

Comment: @StephaneRolland well if there is a portableApp distribution ^^ I could install it without having an openclient. Otherwise I would have to wait until windows 7 is finally installed on my pc - hopefully it does not support VC 6.0 and this will lead to me getting a more recent VC

Comment: you could temporarilly use MS Visual Studio Express. It's free. It's like VS 12.0, but you don't have license for commercial products redistribution.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain as far as I remember... dereferencing a Null pointer, (with MS Visual Studio at least), works, works really well... until you try to access a member function or a data.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I know that VS express is free. But I am not allowed to install any software on my pc at work ...