# Major differences between Visual Studio 6.0 and VS 2010 Compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

Some months ago I posted the following question
[Problem with templates in VS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435910/using-template-functions-in-visual-studio-c-6-0)

The ensuing discussion and your comments helped me to realize that getting my hands on a new compiler was mandatory - or basically they were the final spark which set me into motion. After one month of company-internal "lobbying" I am finally getting VS 2012 !! (thank you guys)

Several old tools which I have to use were developed with VS 6.0
My concerns are that some of these tools might not work with the new Compiler. This is why I was wondering whether somebody here could point out the major differences between VS 6 and VS 2012 - or at least the ones between VS 6 and VS 2010  - the changes from 2010 to 2012 are well documentes online.

Obviously the differences between VS 6.0 and VS 12 must be enormous ... I am mostly concerned with basic things like casts etc. There is hardly any information about VS 6.0 on the web - and I am somewhat at a loss :(

I think I will have to create new projects with the same classes. In the second step I would overwrite the .h and .cpp files with the ones of the old tools. Thus at least I will be able to open the files via the new compiler. Still some casts or Class definitions might not be supported and I would like to have a general idea of what to look for while debugging :)

Comment: Major difference is supporting C++11

Comment: Neither of them fully support C++11.  The major difference is that 6.0 doesn't even support C++03 very well.

Comment: I think you should start by trying to compile the existing codebase using VS 2012. It could well turn out to be the case that VS is more backwards-compatible than you seem to be expecting.

Comment: Most so-called C++ compilers aren't fully standard conforming, but MSVC 6 is so old and broken that it really doesn't deserve to be called a C++ compiler. It was not only written mainly before the standard, until the latest service packs, it did not even got for loop scoping of variables right. The differences are so big that you should consider it being another language, or an incompatible dialect if you will.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Exactly, :-D

Comment: wow !!  - I really had no idea the differences were so huge oO. I tried compiling some of the old code and totally crashed - got something about 300 error messages ... any suggestions on how to proceed ? "re-coding" - everything ?

Comment: @AndreyLujankin: Yes. Go through every single line. Even if it might cmopile, the meaning might have been different in msvc, who knows...

Comment: Getting a new compiler is less fun than I imagined :D ^^

Comment: @NPE It's very backwards compatible, since VC 2012 doesn't even implement C++98 for some major features.  It still uses pre-C++98 name lookup in templates, and still allows binding temporaries to a non-const (which was removed from traditional C++ before 1990).

Comment: @PlasmaHH VC 6.0 is definitely a C++ compiler.  Not C++11, of course.  Not even C++98.  But it's a fairly decent compiler for traditional C++, of say around 1990.  (And in many regards, VS 2012 is pre C++98.  Forget about C++11; VS 2012 still uses "traditional", pre-C++98 name lookup in templates.  And allows initializing non-const references with a temporary, which was forbidden in traditional C++ sometime in the very late 1980s.)

Comment: @AndreyLujankin What kind of error messages?  (The major issue I can see is the scope of variables in a for statement.)

Comment: @PlasmaHH _Most_ of the changes should result in a compiler error, which makes them easy to fix.  For the others, your regression tests should be complete enough to detect them, although finding why the test failed might be a bit of a pain.

Comment: @AndreyLujankin Another major difference might be in the names of header files (I don't remember)---see if you've got things like `<iostream.h>`.  If the compiler can't find a header, you _will_ get hundreds of error messages.  Also: you might try putting a `using namespace std;` at the top of the source file (after the includes).  I abhor this practice in general, but it is useful for migrating code quickly.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You are seriously expecting a codebase that today is based on msvc6 is having a complete enough regression test suite? if any at all? sorry, but rofl...

Comment: @PlasmaHH It should.  Many of the code bases I worked on in the late 1980s/early 1990s had more complete regression tests than some of the stuff I see today.  The importance of testing is not something new; complete and effective regression testing was the rule as far back as the 1960s, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language has evolved significantly since VS 6.0 came out.
VS6.0 is pre-C++98; VS 2012 is C++03, with a few features from
C++11.

Most of the newer language features are upwards compatible;
older code should still work.  Still, VC 6.0 is pre-standard,
and the committee was less concerned about breaking existing
code when there was no previous standard (and implementations
did vary).  There are several aspects of the language (at least)
which might cause problems.

The first is that VC 6.0 still used the old scoping for
variables defined in a `for`.  Thus, in VC 6.0, things like the following
were legal:

```
int findIndex( int* array, int size, int target )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < size && array[i] != target ; ++ i ) {
    }
    return i;
}
```

This will not compile in VC 2012 (unless there is also a global
variable `i`, in which case, it will return *that*, and not the
local one).

IIRC, too, VC 6.0 wasn't very strict in enforcing access
controls and const.  This may not be problem when migrating,
however, because VC 2012 still fails to conform to C++98 in some
of the more flagrant cases, at least with the default options.
(You can still bind a temporary to a non-const reference, for
example.)

Another major language change which isn't backwards compatible
is name lookup in templates.  Here too, however, even in VC
2012, Microsoft has implemented pre-standanrd name lookup (and
I mean pre-C++98).  This is a serious problem if you want to
port your code to other compilers, but it does make migrating
from VC 6.0 to VC 2012 a lot easier.

With regards to the library, I can't remember whether 6.0
supported the C++98 library, or whether it was still
pre-standard (or possibly it supported both).  If your code has
things like `#include <iostream.h>` in it, be prepared for some
differences here: minor for straight forward use of `<<` and
`>>`; major if you implement some complicated `streambuf`.  And
of course, all of the library was moved from global namespace to
`std::`.

For the rest: your code obviously won't use any of the features
introduced after VC 6.0 appeared.  This won't cause migration
problems (since the older features are still supported), but
you'll doubtlessly want to go back, and gradually upgrade the
code once you've migrated.  (You mentionned casts.  This is
a good example: C style casts are still legal, with the same
semantics they've always had, but in new code, you'll want to
avoid them, and least when pointers or references are involved.)

Comment: this is by all means a great answer. Well written, very easy to understand, contains examples !!! - thank you very much. Great job :)